# Don't print the name of the directory to stdout when using here::set_here('path')

Tags: r

I'm using the R package 'here' to define my working directory using the following command at the start of my script:

```
here::set_here(path='/path/to/my_directory/', verbose = F)
```

Every time I run the script it prints this to the console:

```
here() starts at /path/to/my_directory
```

Is there a way to suppress this output? I tried using the `invisible()` function but that didn't work...

Comment: I don't. As I wrote above I'm using the command to DEFINE the working directory so I can navigate around the file system without using absolute file paths

Comment: `invisible` prevents expressions from invoking R’s auto-printing feature on the command line. It’s unrelated to silencing messages inside functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message you’re seeing is printed when you’re attaching the ‹here› package. Simply don’t do that (it’s unnecessary anyway) to prevent it.

Otherwise, load it as follows:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(here))
```

… yeah, not exactly elegant.